# All my relatives are black but am not

Tags: riddle

[image]
All my relatives are black but am not

Comment: Znlor n ohggresyl?

Comment: Hi and welcome to puzzling SE! I see that you've tagged it as a [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle), but where is the riddle? All I can see is an image, with a sentence written below it. Please clarify your question, otherwise it will attract downvotes. Happy puzzling! :)

Answer (score 7):

You are

> an African person with albinism?

Nice photo.

Comment: I ***snorted*** at that one, thanks; needed that laugh.